# Data not replicated in openstreetmap

Tags: google-maps, leaflet, replication, openstreetmap, mapnik

In google maps, when we drag horizontally our data(like markers) will shown in all maps. But in openstreet map data showed in a single world map, not replicated to other maps. 
Any option to show data in all maps or how to replicate the same world map in all time?

Comment: What is a "map" in your context? A specific layer? Please try to explain your problem as detailed as possible, ideally by providing example code.

Comment: crosspost: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/44204/markers-not-showed-in-multiple-maps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to make a wild guess that you're asking whether Leaflet can repeat markers across world copies. If that's the case, yes - [see the Leaflet documentation, and the worldCopyJump option](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-worldcopyjump).